# Code in Java(Android Studio) libgdx, how to calculate for a projectile

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Code in Java(Android Studio) libgdx,... how to calculate for a projectile for a circle(like a ball) when you click/touch the screen and how would you display it? **like shooting a basketball**....for example circle is in 0,0(x,y) with an angle of 50 degrees...
THANKS!!

[image: I want like this]

Comment: The question is not clear. Post and image example and add some code you have tried.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Are you using box2d ?

Comment: If you're not using box2d then what is the initial velocity of your ball ?

Comment: yes i'm using a box2d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using box2d then projectile motion is handled by your box2d engine. You just need to apply linear velocity.

```
float speed,angle;

Vector2 startingVelocity =new Vector2(speed,speed);
startingVelocity.rotate((float) angle - 45);

body.setLinearVelocity(startingVelocity);
```

speed and angle is provided by you.

If you're not using box2d then you need to handle position and velocity of your ball like this.

```
public class TestGame extends Game implements InputProcessor{

    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
    Sprite ball;
    Texture ballTex;
    boolean isFired;

    Vector2 gravity;
    private float throwAngle=50;
    private float deltaTime=2;
    private Vector2 initialVelocity;

    @Override
    public void create() {

        spriteBatch=new SpriteBatch();
        ballTex=new Texture("image/ball.png");
        ball=new Sprite(ballTex);
        ball.setSize(50,50);
        ball.setPosition(0,0);

        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this);
        gravity=new Vector2(0, -Gdx.graphics.getHeight()*.05f);
        float throwVelocity=Gdx.graphics.getWidth()*.3f;
        initialVelocity=new Vector2((float)(throwVelocity*Math.sin(throwAngle * Math.PI / 180)),(float)(throwVelocity*Math.cos(throwAngle * Math.PI / 180)));
    }

    @Override
    public void render() {
        super.render();

        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1,1,1,1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        updateBall();

        spriteBatch.begin();
        ball.draw(spriteBatch);
        spriteBatch.end();
    }

    private void updateBall(){

        if(isFired){

            float delta=Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
            initialVelocity.x=initialVelocity.x+gravity.x*delta*deltaTime;
            initialVelocity.y=initialVelocity.y+gravity.y*delta*deltaTime;

            ball.setPosition(ball.getX()+initialVelocity.x * delta * deltaTime,ball.getY()+initialVelocity.y * delta * deltaTime);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        super.resize(width, height);
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        super.dispose();
        ballTex.dispose();
        spriteBatch.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyUp(int keycode) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyTyped(char character) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {

        isFired=true;
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean mouseMoved(int screenX, int screenY) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean scrolled(int amount) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much, appreciate it.