# Android libgdx, fixed variable for different screen sizes

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Android, libgdx. I'm currently working on a game shooting a basketball, my problem was my throw velocity variable is fixed and when i tried it to a different devices w/ different screen size, the result was failed.
 Any solution? Thanks for the help!

```
float throwVelocity=Gdx.graphics.getWidth()*0.905f;
```

Comment: https://xoppa.github.io/blog/pixels/

Comment: @Paul Natividad http://stackoverflow.com/a/42317348/3445320

Comment: @AbhishekAryan oh yes, do I need to apply this for my screen problem?


float speed,angle;

Vector2 startingVelocity =new Vector2(speed,speed);
startingVelocity.rotate((float) angle - 45);

body.setLinearVelocity(startingVelocity);



, is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Velocity is vector quantity should depend on width and height both.

If you're using box2d then you just need to apply linear velocity.

```
float speed,angle;

Vector2 startingVelocity =new Vector2(speed,speed);
startingVelocity.rotate((float) angle - 45);

body.setLinearVelocity(startingVelocity);
```

speed and angle is provided by you.

Taken reference from :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42317348/3445320

And you should also consider this
https://xoppa.github.io/blog/pixels/

Comment: yeah i need to have an orthographic camera

Comment: @PaulNatividad if you're using with Stage, orthographic camera already there otherwise create your own and use with your game.